# Why does order matter in a middleware file?

Tags: express, middleware

I have an express app that I just added an APM to monitor my app. It wasn't reporting to the APM until I was suggested to require their import at the top of my middleware file. Why does order matter in a middleware file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Order matters in middleware because middleware functions are executed in a sequence and you'd need to execute one before the other in order to utilize its functionality.

For example, let's say you have two middleware functions, the first modifies the `req` object by adding the current user's credentials and the second ends the request-response cycle.
Invoking the second function will terminate the cycle before modifying the `req` object.